# async forEach() in setInterval()

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

I want to poll a list of sources every minute and from the ones that are online pull an array from the source, check if there are valid elements and choose two elements randomly and perform an async action with them. My code looks like.

```
const sources = ['source1', 'source2', 'source3']

setInterval(function() {
  sources.forEach((source) => {
    asyncResolveToArrayIfOnline(source)
      .then((list) => {
        if (list) {
          return Promise.all(list.map((element) => {
            return asyncCheckElement(element).then((trueOrFalse) => {
              return [trueOrFalse, element]
            })
          }))
        }
      })
      .then((arrayOfResults) => {
        if (arrayOfResults) {
          let validElementsArray = []
          arrayOfResults.forEach((validElement) => {
            if (validElement[0]) {
              validElementsArray.push(validElement[1])
            }
          })
          if (validElementsArray.length >= 2) {
            drawTwoElements()
            asyncAction(firstDrawnElement, secondDrawnElement)
          }
        }
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err)
      })
  })
}, 60000)
```

It works most of the times. The error seems to come from the fact, that asyncResolveToArrayIfOnline(source) sometimes source2 resolves while source1 has not been processed to finish and the resolved list is passed to the wrong loop.

Comment: You are starting 3 different promise chains. The result of one promise cannot get into .then of another. The problem happens because of something else. What exactly is throwing? If you still have concerns regarding the parallel execution you could execute them sequentally with 'bluebird' like this Promise.each(sources.map(source => { return asyncResolveToArrayIfOnline(...)}))

Comment: Promise.each and serially works. Could not solve it for parallell. It is not throwing, but the resolve of the asyncResolveToArrayIfOnline(source) from source2 is put in the source1 the times when it resolves before asyncResolveToArrayIfOnline(source) for source1.